# Bootstrap how to make label 100% width?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im using bootstrap, like that:

```
<label>
    <input type="text">
</label>
```

the problem is, `label` is hardcoded with `display: inline-block;` How to get rid of it, or make it nicer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you have bootstrap. Just use the class "form-control" for the textbox. And I suggest you, don't use the 'label' for parent of textbox.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control">
```

> use this code for 100% width of textbox

Answer (score 4):

override it with your own stylesheet with `display:block`

Answer (score 2):

You can try it with `<label style="display: block;"></label>`

Answer (score 1):

It's frowned upon these days, but I believe styling the label inline should override it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label style="display:block;">
    <input type="text">
</label>
```

Show solve your query